# How can I initialize "array a" that contains "array b" that contains "array a"

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I need to create two arrays, Array A, and Array B, Array A needs to contain Array B and vice versa. The problem is that object bar is initialized after the object foo, therefore the value of foo.arrayA[0] is undefined. Is there a way to do this without dynamically setting the value of foo.arrayA[0] after everything has loaded?

```
var skra = {
    arrayX: [foo, bar]
};

var foo = {
    arrayA: [bar, skra]
};

var bar = {
    arrayB: [foo, skra]
};
console.log(foo.arrayA[0]);
console.log(bar.arrayB[0]);
```

output:

```
undefined
{arrayA: Array(2)}
```

Comment: `var a = [], var b = [a]; a.push(b);`

Comment: Fairly important question: why? Other than "is this something I can do?" (to which the answer is "yes"), what are you actually doing that makes you think you need this?

Comment: I am trying to use objects as ways to store map data for a "game" the objects will have two arrays one that contains the tilemap data and one that contains which map to switch to once you reach the edge, two bordering maps will need to have a reference to each other.

Comment: What I've done is I used a function instead of an array, this way I can use a switch case to return my value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var bar = {};
var skra = {
    arrayX: [foo, bar]
};

var foo = {
    arrayA: [bar, skra]
};

Object.assign(bar, {
    arrayB: [foo, skra]
});
console.log(foo.arrayA[0]);
console.log(bar.arrayB[0]);
```

I hope this works for you.